# How to pass UIControl as a function parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For example, I have one function. In this function as a parameter I have to pass some UIControl like UILabel, UITextFile, UIButton, etc. How can I do this:

```
func passDicData(controll : UIControll){
    //code
}
```

Used like:

```
passDicData(UILabel)
```

Comment: Inheritance: `UILabel`|`UIView`|`UIResponder`|`NSObject`. `UILabel` doesn't inherit from `UIControl`, while `UITextField` and `UIButton` do.

Comment: so I can access only two UIControl using this method?

Comment: But they all inherits from `UIView`. So you could use `UIView` instead of `UIControl`. Also when you do `passDicData(UILabel)`, you are passing the Class? Really? Or you want an instance of an object?

Comment: Thanks @Larme bro it's working for me.

Answer (score 2):

//Use UIView

```
func passDicData(control:UIView){
        //code
}


passDicData(UILabel(frame: .zero))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is `UIControl`, not `UIControll`.

Moreover, the common ancestor of the `UILabel`, `UITextField`, and `UIButton` is `UIView`, see for example this [scheme](https://iosdevelopmenttutorials.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/uikit_classes.jpg).

```
func passDicData(view: UIView){
    //code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way,

```
func passDicData(control: AnyClass){
    print(control.class())
}
```

and call it like this way,

```
passDicData(control: UILabel.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use `UIControl` as a parameter:

```
func passDicData(controll : UIControl){
    //code
}
```

However, you will **NOT** be able to call this function like this:

```
passDicData(UILabel)
```

That's because

1. In your example, you are not creating an instance of an UILabel, you are just using its type. In order to pass the instance you should initialize an `UILabel` first, e.g., `passDicData(UILabel())`
2. UILabel is not a subclass of `UIControl`

Instead you could use `UIView` or `UIResponder`, both of them are super classes of `UILabel`

```
func passDicData(responder : UIResponder){
    //code
}

passDicData(UILabel())
```